# Ignore Entities by Default

Tags: entity-framework

I have an existing database, to which I'd like to add Entity Framework mappings for just a handful of tables/entities. Is there a way to ignore all entities by default, and then selectively include them?

I have this in the context constructor to not migrate changes:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<Context>());
```

And then I have the following fluent code to map the existing entities:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Cube>()
        .Map(e => e.ToTable("tblCubes"))
        .HasKey(e => e.CubeId);
    ...
```

However, when I run any EF queries, I get the error:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation.
EntityType 'xyz' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType
```

Rather than using `modelBuilder.Ignore<xyz>();` on every existing and future entity, can't I just get EF to ignore all by default, and only map those I choose/include?

EDIT============

One of my EF entities (CubeFact) has relational properties to other classes like this one below to the Year class:

```
private Year _year;
public Int16 YearId { get; set; }
public Year Year { get { return _year ?? (_year = Year.GetYearById(YearId)); } set { _year = value; } }
```

The Year class then links to a Fact class, which is one of the classes failing validation. But neither the Year class nor the Fact class have been explicitly mapped. Does EF follow these relationships and then validate, even if I haven't explicitly told it about the relationships?

Comment: Are you using Database First? You can use the Code First approach with an existing database, and it will only care about the tables and fields you tell it about. (Of course you should set the initializer to null in a way similar to how you have it set in your code.)

Comment: I'm using CodeFirst. I was a bit surprised it picked up all the other POCOs and tried to validate them - I would have thought it would only include the classes I explicitly mapped via DbSet<>.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't have other POCOs set up with configurations? That's really weird. Are they model classes of things you are passing up to other software layers?

Comment: Nothing else set up - just installed Entity Framework, then literally added the DbSet, the Context constructor, and the OnModelCreating override (which calls the base, although I tried removing that). So pretty much just the code above. No other software layers, or anything like that.

Comment: That's really weird. Maybe check [Julia Lerman's blog](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/) and see if she has anything back there? It's been too long since I've read the Code First book.

Comment: does any other entity refer to `xyz`? EF will infer a DbSet for any referenced entities.

Comment: @DrewJordan Not directly. One entity I have in OnModelCreating is the `CubeFact` entity, which has a Foreign Key relationship to the `Year` class/table, which is a Foreign Key for the `Fact` class/table, which is giving the `xyz` error. But I'm not defining `Year` nor `Fact` in the OnModelCreating code, so EF shouldn't traverse to them?

Comment: mmm... maybe, but that's where I'd start. Can you temporarily tell it to `Ignore()` them and see what happens?

Comment: This can only happen if in your mapped classes you've got references to, or collections of, other classes that are not mapped. For instance, if `CubeFact` has a property `Fact` (of type `Fact`), rather that only a primitive `FactId`, EF would require a `Fact` mapping too. The solution would be to mark these reference/collection properties as not mapped.

Comment: @DrewJordan If I `Ignore()`, then it validates fine. @Gert I've updated the question to show the relationships I have to other classes.

Comment: Sean, I think you should re think your Database Design from the standpoint of the Database. You shouldn't try and Design a database using EF, that is not what it was build for. Its an ORM, object relational mapper. It will just map you tables to objects. Go in SQL Studio and design your database there.

Comment: @Callum The database has been designed completely independently. However, there is a need for very flexible queries on some of the tables which Entity Framework handles very efficiently. So I'm trying to just model those existing tables with EF. However, I don't understand what you're saying: the point of "Code First" is surely to design the database in EF? (Not that I'm doing that, i.e. I'm **not** generating the database from the EF code.)

Comment: Well, code first *can* be used to design a database - but really it's just a way to express a database with out having a **edmx** or model designer, or getting the Database First approach to generate you a whole or crap. I see it as Code First interaction. A code only approach to interacting with the database (which is why I love it). Don't forget about `context.Database.ExecuteStoreCommand` or the query one. These are invaluable to enabling you write stored procs.

Comment: In this sense, you don't do `Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<Context>());` because you're working with an existing database. Just get the connection string correct, and away you go!

Comment: Instead of the `Database.SetInitializer()` you have, you'll want to do `Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null)` as that will tell Code First to not make any changes to the database. Without anything there, you could alter/drop columns, etc, without knowing it.